# Error: Attempt to give DATA in type-declaration

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran77

## Background

Compiling [floppy](http://www.netlib.org/floppy/) for [Linux](http://www.netlib.org/floppy/contents.html). Installed Fortran as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install fort77
```

## Problem

```
$ make
f77 -c -w touppr.for
   touppr:
Error on line 12: attempt to give DATA in type-declaration
```

## Source

The entire source file for `touppr.for`:

```
      character*(*) function touppr(char)
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*--- Converts a string to upper case
*
*--- Input
*    char - string to be converted
*--- Output
*    touppr - uppercase char as value of function
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      character*(*) char
      character*26 cup /'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'/
      character*26 clo /'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'/
      save cup,clo
      touppr = char
      do 1 i=len(char),1,-1
         ipos = index(clo,char(i:i))
         if(ipos.ne.0) touppr(i:i) = cup(ipos:ipos)
    1 continue
      end
```

Lines 12 and 13 are:

```
      character*26 cup /'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'/
      character*26 clo /'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'/
```

## Question

What is wrong with lines 12 and 13 that prevents the code from compiling, and how would you fix it?

Comment: note, while not standard this is a common extension. If you have many such issues you might try a different compiler, or see if your compiler has some option flags to accept extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not legal Fortran 77 or any other standard. The error message is quite correct. The data statement must be separate, or an initialization statement from Fortran 90 must be used. Or rather define them as PARAMETER, but then delete the SAVE.

The following will compile using f77:

```
  character*26 cup 
  character*26 clo 
  data cup/'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'/
  data clo/'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'/
  save cup,clo
```